# What type of pumps are most energy efficient to lift 200 liters of water over 15 feet?

Tags: motor, efficiency, water, fluid-pump

Trying to design a rain-water harvesting system for our home. A long-term goal for me is to go "off-grid", or reduce dependency on grid-power, as much as possible. My need is to evacuate about 200 liters of rain water collected in a container, i.e. lift it, to a larger roof-top, overhead tank. A key objective is to use minimal electrical energy, and thus looking for high-efficiency pump, for this task. Another objective is to keep the system cost low.

My calculation using:
1. Catchment area size in my house (75 sq.mtr)
2. Peak daily rainfall (240 mm, over 12 peak hours)
3. Collector size (200 L)

Using this [online tool](http://www.calctool.org/CALC/other/default/rainfall), tells me that peak performance desirable for pump would be to lift 25 liters/min over 15feet. Not sure how big/powerful a pump that requires, however, I do not need to be able to lift the entire rainfall to the overhead tank, but only as much as the intended tank capacity is (say 2000L). For that, at 25 L/min I need to run the pump daily for 80 minutes, say 10min cycles 8-times daily.

Don't know a lot about pumps, but in what I've read so far, looks like "Rotary - Centrifugal", AC-powered pumps have high efficiency. Also, I require what appears to be "self-priming" pump. However, is this really what I need ?

Have gone through the FAQ, done some prior research. Hopefully this isn't a terrible or off-topic question.

Comment: Irony! The water came down from thousands of feet above and now you're struggling how to recover 15. :)

Comment: Pump efficiency is not fixed for a given pump and depends on discharge, head, etc. In your case, you need about 9800 Joules (2.8 Watt-hours) of energy to raise 200 litres of water by 5 meters (energy = mass x g x height).  If this can be pumped slowly, you could do it with a very small, low power pump.  You will need to look at pump curves to figure out the best combination of flow rate vs efficiency for different types of pumps.

Comment: Not an electrical engineering question and should be closed.  Also an overlapping question from OP on same subject.

Comment: @mikeY, read SE and EE FAQ before posting, and it asked me to explicitly keep question focused and not mix multiple questions. Which questions from OP (myself) do you consider overlapping ? How is "efficient pump" not an EE question ?

Comment: This question really is borderline imho. That said, have you checked DIY.stackexchange.com, the Home improvement stack?

Comment: Just to scare you, I read an article saying, since the rainwater is feeding sources of municipal water, the City can fine people to prevent them from collecting rainwater. (Although this sounds ridiculous to me, I would check before making any large investment).

Comment: Thanks @Passerby. Will check Home-Improvement DIY SE site as well.

Comment: @BSEE, yes I am aware of such ridiculous local laws, but in spite of many other ridiculous laws in my country, we've still not enacted something like this. So, for the moment, I think I am safe :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about **electrical** engineering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's weight of the head of water that is a problem to non-centrifugal pumps.

Centrifugal pumps naturally do this better than the flood pumps that you can buy for cellars etc and they do cost more but, do run more efficiently.

I've just bought a non-centrifugal flood-pump to get rid of waste water up a 10m rise and to get it to work I lowered the head weight by reducing the outlet pipe diameter to 19mm from 32mm (recommended). It is a 1kW pump and although it can move stuff really quickly it isn't an efficient type of pump with a large head height.

Cost about £75.00 which isn't bad for 1kW.

You might also consider a shut-off valve when pumping is finished so it all doesn't leak back down.

You get a better pump with centrifugal but it's the prevalence of cheap flood pumps and the fact they are not "food quality" which makes centrifugal pumps look expensive. Flood pumps are usually totally submersible to make like easier on the user. Basically a plug and play and they have a float switch for off. Suits me draining water from my Koi pond. You want a centrifugal pump and self-priming but watch out - get a food-safe one and you might also need a reverse-osmosis nitrate filter for what you collect before drinking.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Andy. To be sure that I understood the answer - are you saying that centrifugal pumps are costlier than non-centrifugal pumps ? Good point about shut-off valve, will keep that in mind.

Comment: Still, not enough reputations to up-vote, but this is a useful answer.

Comment: @jay You get a better pump with centrifugal but it's the prevalence of cheap flood pumps and the fact they are not "food quality" which makes centrifugal pumps look expensive. You have enough rep now jay. Flood pumps are usually totally submersible to make like easier on the user. Basically a plug and play and they have a float switch for off. Suits me draining water from my Koi pond. You want a centrifugal and self-priming but watch out - get a food safe one and you might also need a reverse-osmosis nitrate filter for what you collect before drinking.

Comment: Up-vote requires 15 reps, so still a bit to go. The centrifugal pumps I am looking at to purchase locally, don't seem to claim being "food grade", but that may also be because local regulations do not require such labelling. They do say things like "for residential use" (and "agricultural use", "industrial use" etc.)